# Is it possible to continue torrent downloads from another client?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I downloaded a torrent file using Bitlord, and because it doesn't have features like [initial seeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-seeding), I decided to use uTorrent. I've already tried to continue it. What I did was:

- Opened the original torrent file in uTorrent.
- Target where the incomplete Bitlord incomplete file was.

But it seems that uTorrent isn't detecting the file and it makes another copy of it and starts to download from the beginning. I'm at about 80 percent and there are only 18 seeds and 17 leeches. My connection is slow, so I really have to use initial seeding.

Other details:

- I've reformatted the original machine where I downloaded it.
- Also didn't copy the original application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You'd need the original torrent file, start the download, stop it, replace the downloaded file from the new instance with the old one, then force recheck.

Comment: when you say replace, do you mean delete it. Because when I put it to the same directory, it doesn't say it will replace. Though they have the same file name

Comment: @nrew don't delete. make utorrent save in the same directory as bitlord was saving the file.

Comment: I did the mentioned steps for Vuze with files previously downloading by uTorrent Web with 50% and 51% completion, but Vuze gives 0 and 0.1% progress for them after force recheck. The torrent file is the same.
This is very strange for me.

Comment: that's wierd. I do wonder if the two of them handle files differently

Answer (score 0):

Just download the original file all over again from torrent while downloading meta data it automatically detects and rechecks it.

Comment: The accepted answer already gives this information. Please avoid posting answers to old and already answered questions when you do not have something substantially new to add.